# Implementing pthreads in .h and .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, pthreads, pthreads-win32

The normal way to pass function as arguments in pthreads for pthread_create method is

```
pthread_create(&thread,NULL,func,(void*)arg)
```

while func() is declared/defined as

```
void* func(void* arg);
```

but whenever I want to call pthread_create it in separate .cpp in visual studio 2012 it gives following error, as shown in the pic

[image: The error in visual studio]

but the error goes away if I define the function static.

```
static void* func(void* arg);
```

**Any suggestions how to pass it without error without making it static?**

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `AppendData_Linux` is *member function* of `XMLParse` class, and that can't convert to pointer to *normal (non-member) function* required by `pthread_create`.

Here is solution:

```cpp
class X {
   void* arg;
public:
   void* func() { ... }

   static void* thunk(void* self) {
     return reinterpret_cast<X*>(self)->func();
   }
};

X obj;
pthread_create(thread, NULL, &X::thunk, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&obj));
```

Comment: `thunk` shall be static member function. _Conceptually_, you can treat member function `void* X::func(void* arg)` as normal function `void* func(X* this, void* arg)`.